# Change the path of an Excel file linked to Access 2011 with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was trying something more fancy and did post on accessforums, where I got got no responses and on programmers access, where I got links to more reading material, but which did not help me - probably due to my lack of VBA expertise.
I have done lots of other programming like PHP and Arduino, but VBA is new for me, although I been watching hours of videos, they don't quite cover what I want to do.

After 4 days of researching an failed attempts, I have simplified my approach and I would appreciate some "real" help with actual code.

Scenario:
I have multiple Excel source file with 9 tabs each.
All the source files are in the same directory, (not in the same directory as the database)
Only one source is ever linked.
Each tab of the source file is a linked table within Access.

Objective:
I wish regularly switch source files.

Method:
I want to replace only the connect file property (i.e. the full file path) for each of the 9 sheets/tabs that use the particular file.
The full path must be "picked up" from my form and applied on an event e.g. on closing of form.

Progress:
I have built a form in which I can enter the file name to use and which calculates the full path to the file in question.
I have a button on the form, which is used to close the form.

Code:

> ```
> Private Sub Form_Close()
> Dim dbs As Database
> Dim tdf As TableDef
> Dim sfl As String
> Dim basePath As String
> Dim sName As String
>
> Set dbs = CurrentDb
> Set sfl = "SourceData_"
> Set sName = "JoeSmith"
> Set basePath = "D:\Databases\BOM Consolidator\data_source"
>
> ' Loop through all tables in the database.
> For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
>     If InStr(10, tdf.Connect, sfl, 1) > 10 Then
>         tdf.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & basePath & sfl & sName & "\" & dbs
>         Err = 0
>         On Error Resume Next
>         tdf.RefreshLink     ' Relink the table.
>         If Err <> 0 Then
>         End If
>     End If
> Next tdf End Sub
> ```

In the above I am entering the path etc directly just to get it working first.
Access froze :(
Help would be appreciated.
Posting this before I try a restart.

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code and debug it so you can figure out where access starts to freeze?

Answer (score 0):

After a restart it is not freezing.
It is saying I have a missing object.
The first line is highlighted in yellow, so I assume something must go in the parenthesis, but no idea what.

If it was a function, I would normally put a variable that is not declared inside the function. This being a subroutine, I was not expecting it to ask for something...

Ultimately I will turn it into a function, sothat I can provide the file name.

A clue to what is needed on the first line please...?

Oh also I am using "Code Builder" - is that the correct option to use with closing a form?